# CSS. Link doesn't works with input:focus

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

There is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc6L323f/2/) with my problem.

As I can understand -- link doesn't work, because when I click on the link, link disappear because :focus isn't active anymore. But I can't come up with solution.

I think it's very common problem, but I didn't found any information about this.

Thanks for any help.

**CSS**:

```
#search:focus + #results {
    display: block;
}

#results {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input id="search" type="text"/>

<ul id="results">
    <li><a href="/1"> First </a></li>
    <li><a href="/2"> Second </a></li>
    <li><a href="/3"> Third </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a hover method to #results:

`#results:hover{display:block;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/gc6L323f/3/

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This is pretty clever :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest in your case to include also `:hover` pseudo class and make the `#results` object visible on hover.

Like this :

```
#results:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

You can check [working demo](http://jsbin.com/qisucunafe/1/edit?html,css,output).